# Magento 'Add to Cart' button displaying 'code' on click

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, controllers

I am new to Magento. I have added a new controller to display "Hello world" and the theme used is 'base/default'. I have added a new category and a new product inside it, which are both showing up. However, when I add that product to cart by clicking Add to Cart, I get redirected to a new page which simply displays a lot of code, like this:-

```
{"product_name":"Rolex","message":"Rolex was added into cart.","update_blocks":[{"key":".block.block-cart","value":"<div class=\"block block-cart\">\n
....
....
Proceed to Checkout<\/span><\/span><\/button>\n<\/li>\n                                                            <li><a href=\"http:\/\/localhost\/magento\/index.php\/checkout\/multishipping\/\" title=\"Checkout with Multiple Addresses\">Checkout with Multiple Addresses<\/a>\n<\/li>\n                                        <\/ul>\n                    <\/div>\n    <\/div>\n<\/div>\n"}],"r":"success"}
```

This is the url I've been redirected to:-

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9tYWdlbnRvL2luZGV4LnBocC9jYXRhbG9nL2NhdGVnb3J5L3ZpZXcvcy93YXRjaGVzL2lkLzgv/product/1/form_key/ocE8xrUJjGT9qIbu/
```

Although this is happening, when I return to my homepage, it is seen that the product has been added to cart. What is happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your code,you have using Ajax Cart and due to `any conflation  at  JavaScript`  that addCart ajax request not working  and from `CartController.php` 's function addAction, a json data  after addto cart of a product.That means that you `cannot cart using general page refresh` and need to `send request  using Ajax`

That addAction return update_blocks, cart page in Json format.In this case you need to remove json return from CartController file

Comment: That worked like MAGIC :D . I had installed an AJAX cart extension during my initial days and forgot all about it. Now I disabled it and got the required output. I have no idea how you debugged it without even getting full code, could you point me in the right direction? Thanks a ton anyway :)

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Im too curious to know, how did you realize that AJAX was working? did you find out from the URL?

Comment: Hi @AmitBera can u tell me which code remove. so it's working fine for me..